# Including value from temp table slows down query

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that uses a temporary table to make some joins in a select clause. The select clause contains the value from the Id column of the temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
RootVal INT
)
```

The Select looks like this:

```
Select value1, value2, #TempTable.Id AS ValKey 
  From MainTable INNER JOIN #TempTable ON  MainTable.RootVal = #TempTable.RootVal
```

The query takes over a minute to run in real life but if I remove the "#TempTable.Id" from the select list it runs in a second.

Does anyone know why there is such a huge cost to including a value from a #temp table compared to just using it in a join?

Comment: How many rows? Index on temp table? MainTable.RootVal datatype?

Comment: Around 500000, yes there is an index on RootVal in the temp table as well as on MainTable.RootVal. Im going to redo it so I dont need to have the value from the tamp table but I simply cant understand what  the problem is.

Comment: Can you add query plans please?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely:

- data type mismatch
  eg nvarchar vs int
- lack of index on MainTable.RootVal
  Why have `Id` as PK and then JOIN on another column?

Comment: Its int everywhere and I have an index on the RootVal column in the temp table, no need for the primary key though of course. Im completely stumped..